# Install Skype for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, skype, 15.04

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed, but I can't find Skype in it. Can someone tell me how to download and install it, please! Because on Skype site there's only Skype for Ubuntu 12.04, and in the Software Center there's not Skype at all.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure Skype for 12.04 will work in later releases.

Comment: @It'sWillem, yes, it's still working.

Comment: Then install that.

Answer (score 0):

Just download version for 12.04, it works great on all ubuntu relieses. Also, don't forget sni-qt, for skype indicator to work properly:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

After that restart computer, and you're good to go :)

Comment: hvala brate,sredio sam to

Comment: Super, nema na cemu :)